# Assigning values to Dictionary Array overrides the existing values

Tags: c#, .net

I have below code:

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] Records = new Dictionary<string, string>[2];         
Dictionary<string, string> newFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

newFields["Item"] = "M1";
newFields["Value"] = "V1";

Records[0] = newFields;

newFields["Item"] = "M2"; // This also changes values in Records[0]
newFields["Value"] = "V2";

Records[1] = newFields;
```

But as soon as I assign newFields again, it also changes values in Records[0]??????????????

Comment: You should read up on reference types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you assing a reference of `newFields` to `Records[0]`!

Try this:

```
/* .... */

Records[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>(newFields);

/* .... */
```

Answer (score 3):

`Records[0] = newFields;` passes a reference, not a copy of that dictionary. That's why both `Records[0]` and `newFields` point to the same object.

To make a copy of existing `Dictionary` instance use that:

```
Records[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>(newFields);
```